# Difference between current_path vs release_path in Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

What is the difference between the `current_path` and `release_path` path variables in Capistrano, as in

```
task :path do
    on roles :app do
        puts "Release path: #{release_path}"
        puts "Current path: #{current_path}"
    end
end
```

Does the `current_path` always contain the most up to date code?

Answer (score 10):

Since this hasn't got a satisfactory answer I'll add what I've found out.

Looking at [this blog post](http://www.freelancingdigest.com/articles/capistrano-variables/) we can see where *path* variables point:

> current_path – path of deploy_to + current_dir (e.g. /u/apps/example/current ) 
>   release_path – path of releases_path + release_name (e.g. /u/apps/example/releases/20100624000000 )

So to answer your question: yes, `current_path` does point to the most up to date code (the most recent deployment). It points here through a symlink to the latest release directory. Take a look at the [capistrano structure](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/structure/) if you're interested in what all the folders mean.

The difference with `release_path` is that it points to the path of the release you are currently deploying. This is useful if you want to reference a file in your repo during the deployment, such as run a script.

However, `release_path` is only updated during the `deploy:starting` namespace, at any other time, it's exactly the same as `current_path`.
See this [github isssue](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/765) for more information.

My particular use case was I wanted to run a `composer install` using the `composer.phar` that's located in the root of my repo. So, following [the documentation](https://github.com/capistrano/composer/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/composer.rake) I did this:

```ruby
SSHKit.config.command_map[:composer] = "#{release_path}/composer.phar"
```

But that didn't work, because at the time this is defined, `release_path` still points to the `current_path`.

The workaround I found for this comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25850619/1393498) and it's to evaluate the `release_path` lazily:

```ruby
SSHKit.config.command_map[:composer] = lambda { "#{release_path}/" + fetch(:src_path) + "/composer.phar" }
```

So as long as the variable is accessed after the `deploy:starting` namespace, `release_path` will be set as we expect it.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been searching for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I feel compelled to answer here to clarify some things about **current_path** and **release_path**

Capistrano works in stages, so for the sake of this answer I will describe the important stages as follows.

### Stage 1: before **current_dir** is relinked

In my version of Capistrano that I'm looking at, the "linking" of the 'current' directory occurs in task

```
deploy:create_symlink
```

But you should check your capistrano setup for the exact taskname.  It is easy to see in the capistrano terminal output, just look for the sshkit call to "ln -s".

**PRIOR** to this step running:

- **current_dir** is the path to the symlink, pointing to the **last** directory creating by the last [not current] run of capistrano.  **NOT REALLY CURRENT IS IT?  Or not for long anyway.....**
- **release_dir** is the most recently checked out version created in this run of capistrano.

So take special note, anything working in **current_dir** at this stage is working **in the wrong place**.

### Stage 2: after **current_dir** is relinked

**AFTER** the symlinking step runs [it will run "ln -s" on the **release_dir**, linking to **current_dir** (its not really a directory, its a link.   Anyway.....)]

- **current_dir** is the path to the symlink, pointing to the **release_dir**.  Now it **really is current**.
- **release_dir** is the most recently checked out version created in this run of capistrano.

At this stage, it no longer matters whether your tasks are working in **release_dir** or **current_dir**, they are pointing at the "same" files on the disk.

### Why is this important?

Working before the symlink is changed is typically preferable because, if there's a failure, nothing is disrupted.   At this stage, you must use **release_dir**.

If you are working after the symlink has changed, you could still use **release_dir**.   If you are using **current_dir**, ask yourself why not use **release_dir**,
and ask yourself why you have these build steps running **after** the symbolic link changes.  If you can move them before the symlink changes, you should.   In
the setup I am looking at, I do this with

```
before "deploy:create_symlink",  "a_task_that_must_use_release_dir"
```

If you are working in **current_dir** after the symlink changes, and before your webserver restarts, and you encounter a problem, you may have trashed your environment.

Does this make **current_dir** evil?   I don't think so, with great power comes great responsibility.

Comment: Stage 1: I would argue that current_dir is not the wrong place. Current version only changes if everything goes right so I think the semantic fits whatever the stage.

Answer (score -2):

Each time you are deploying Rails application with Capistrano a new directory will created with newer version as filename in `Releases` Directory. This directory contains most updated code. and the `current symlink directory` will point to the latest created directory to run the application.

The tasks rake,bundle etc will run on shared path directory which creates separate directories

we can revert back a release usning `rollback` command like

```
 cap deploy:rollback # capistrano 2
 cap stage_name rollback  #capistrano 3
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Answer is inconclusive