# Capistrano returning wrong release_path

Tags: ruby, gruntjs, capistrano, bower, capistrano3

I have a question about capistrano version 3.2.1. In my deploy.rb file I'm using the following line:

```
set :theme_path, "#{release_path}/web/app/themes/myproject"
```

The variable release_path is not showing to latest release folder, lets say **201409151420** as it should, but it is pointing to folder **current**, so the output is:

```
DEBUG[68031037] Command: cd /var/www/myproject/current/web/app/themes/myproject && ( WP_ENV=staging /usr/bin/env npm install --silent )
```

The output should be:

```
DEBUG[68031037] Command: cd /var/www/myproject/201409151420/web/app/themes/myproject && ( WP_ENV=staging /usr/bin/env npm install --silent )
```

Does anyone know, why the release_path variable isn't showing to the proper folder?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: ```current_path``` is the latest ```release_path```. So what is the problem? Doesn't it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it should work if you evaluate your `theme_path` lazily:

<s>`set(:theme_path) { "#{release_path}/web/app/themes/myproject" }`</s>

```
set :theme_path, lambda { "#{release_path}/web/app/themes/myproject" }
```

The value you are seeing is expected if `release_path` is not defined (see [dsl/paths.rb](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/3e664b01f28dd33ce700254f41a6bdbdeccca092/lib/capistrano/dsl/paths.rb)):

```
def release_path
  fetch(:release_path, current_path)
end
```

That is, the default value for `release_path` is `current_path`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, now I'm getting the error: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

Comment: @janhocevar, sorry, the DSL changed slightly between Cap 2 and 3. I've updated my answer.